# Pyramid layer position from a ordered list position

Tags: algorithm

At the beginning it seemed to be a simple problem but now I'm not so sure.

I have a list of players, ordered by their ranking.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

I must show this list as a pyramid, where each layer increase by one the number of players it can have. So, the first player on the ranking is at the top of the pyramid, second and the third is on the second layer and so on...

```
      1 
    2 , 3
  4 , 5 , 6
7 , 8 , 9 , 10
```

I wonder if it was possible to get the pyramid layer number (LN) from the ranking position (RP). For instance:

```
1 RP = 1 LN
3 RP = 2 LN
5 RP = 3 LN
8 RP = 4 LN
```

Tried to create a formula to get this value, but it's clear now that my math needs reinforcements. So... here I am.

X RP = Y LN?

Comment: is it always contained by 10 arrays? the number maybe vary but is it always 10 combination of numbers?

Comment: What would the pyramid look like with only 7 players? Is this invalid or would just the 8, 9 and 10 be missing above?

Comment: @shadrachJabonir it can be larger than that. It could be any number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let i be at level L.

Then the previous (L-1) levels have L(L-1)/2 numbers. In other words, and since there are x numbers in level x, we know that

x(x-1)/2 < i ≤ x(x-1)/2 + x

or equivalently

x^2 - x - 2i < 0

and

x^2 + x - 2i ≥ 0

The discriminants of the above two equations are D = 1 + 8i.
Clearly the level L has to be below the positive root of the first quadratic; that is

L < (1+√(1+8i))/2

and be at least the positive root of the second quadratic, that is

L ≥ (-1+√(1+8i))/2

So, all we have to do is take the ceiling of the last one.

In C terms this value, as an integer, is

(int) ceil((-1.0 + sqrt(1.0 + 8.0 * i)) / 2.0)

Nice problem!

Answer (score 2):

`LN(RP=x) = ceil((sqrt(1+8x)-1)/2)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two loops, the outer loop is for each level and the inner loop is for the number of digits in the level.

```
int pyramidCount(int val){
    if (val == 0)
        return 0;
    int count =0; 
    for (int i=1;i <=val;i++){
        for(int j=0;j <i; j++ ){
            count ++;
            if(count == val) return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```